# Why is my awk script creating empty sequence index files?

Tags: awk

I would like to use awk to read through an existing fasta file (called R2) and create a new file (called I2) with select information and formatting. Here is the format of R2:

```
@K00337:359:HGJV5BBXY:7:1101:1499:1314 1:N:0:NATCCATG
ANCTCGTCCTGCAGGTTTAAAACTTCAAAAATGCATAAAGAATATTCATTAAAACAGACTTCTCTGTACTATTACAATCCATCAATGCTTGTCTGACTGGAATCCATCTGAAAAACAAAGGAAAAATTACAACCCATATCTCTCTGTAATA
+
A#A-AFJJJJJJJJF<A-FFJJJFJAJJJJJFJFJ-<FJFJFFJJF<<-JAJJAJJJJJFJJJJJJFAFFJFF<FFJ<FAJ-<<JF-----AFFA7-F7AJ---FAF7AFJJJ<-A-A-7-A7FJJ-<JJ<F-77<JFFF-A7-FF--<-7
@K00337:359:HGJV5BBXY:7:1101:1681:1314 1:N:0:NGCCATCT
GNTACCCTGCAGCAAAGCCAGCAAGAGATTAACCCCTCTACAGCCCCAGCCACTTTCCATCTTCACTACCTCTCTACCGCAAATTACAATCCCGATCTGCCAGCATAACTCACTCACGTGAGATGGTCAAAGTAGACAGGGGTATTTAAAC
+
A#AFFFJJJJJJFFJJJFAJAFJJFJF<FF--JJJ<J<FFJJAAF7FJ<AFJJA-F7JJJJ--<<FA-A<77---<<<-A-F-AFF7---<-F77--A-FA77---<7A-<FF7AA--<77----<7<<<-A--A-77-------7-<--A
@K00337:359:HGJV5BBXY:7:1101:1824:1314 1:N:0:NCCTATCA
CNGCAACTCTGCAGAAATTGGCATAAGTAAAGAGGAACCCAATTATAGTAGCCAAGACAATGGGGGAAAAGTTTCAAAGGCATTTCAGAGACCAGTTGGCAGCCCCTTCCATCGTAGGCCCAGAGGCCTAGGAGGAAAGAATGGGTTTGTG
+
A#AAA-FAAFAJ7JF7J<JFJJ7J<-FFJFJJJA7FFJJAFFJFJJJFJJ-FAFJJJJJJAF-FAAA7FJF7F-FJFJJFFJ-FAFA--AF<---77--AF77AJ---7AA-<7----777<F-AAFJFJFJ-77-------7A---F-A-
@K00337:359:HGJV5BBXY:7:1101:2067:1314 1:N:0:NTCCTTCT
ANCGTTGCTGCAGCTGGGATAGAGCAACCCCCTACACCAGTACAGTTTTGGAACTGACTGGCTGAGTAACAGTTCTGCACTCATGCCAACATAGGAGAAAGCTTTACTTCTCTTTACAGTCCAGTTCTGTTAAACAGATCTCCTTTTTGAG
+
A#A-F<FAJAFJ-AA7A<FFJFFJJJJJJJJJFJJJJJJFFAFJFA<FJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJFJJJFJJJJ-FFJ-AFA<FJFFJ<7FJJJJAJA-A<F-AF-7AAF---A7<A-FJFJFJ<<A<A7--FJ<-7A-FFFF<F----AAJ7
```

And here is the desired format of I2:

```
@K00337:359:HGJV5BBXY:7:1101:1499:1314 1:N:0:NATCCATG
NATCCATG
+
#AAFFJFJ
@K00337:359:HGJV5BBXY:7:1101:1681:1314 1:N:0:NGCCATCT
NGCCATCT
+
#AA--AF-
@K00337:359:HGJV5BBXY:7:1101:1824:1314 1:N:0:NCCTATCA
NCCTATCA
+
#<AAFFJJ
@K00337:359:HGJV5BBXY:7:1101:2067:1314 1:N:0:NTCCTTCT
NTCCTTCT
+
#<-A-AFF
```

Since this is sequence data, each new sequence entry begins with the "@" symbol (i.e. every four lines). The first and third lines will always be the same between the two files. However, the second line of I2 will be the last 8 characters of the first line of R2, and the fourth line of I2 will be the first 8 characters of the fourth line of R2. Here is the code I have been using to accomplish this:

```
zcat Undetermined_R2_001.fq.gz |awk '{ 
if ((NR%4)==1) 
    print $0 '\n' substr($2,7,8); 
else if ((NR%4)==3) 
    print $0; 
else if ((NR%4)==4) 
    print substr($0,1,8); 
}' | gzip > ./Undetermined_I2_001.fq.gz
```

It takes a few minutes to create the I2 file so I know that it is able to read through the R2 file, but the I2 file that is created is always empty. Would anyone with more awk experience be able to help me debug this small bit of code?

Comment: `NR%4` can never equal 4. mod4 is 0,1,2,3. But the other lines should print.

Comment: beware: `awk '... print ... '\n' ... '` won't print a newline (consider the other single-quotes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
... | awk  '{r=NR%4} 
        r==1{print $0 ORS substr($2,7,8)} 
        r==3{print}
        r==0{print substr($0,1,8)}' | ...
```

Comment: Hi karakfa, thank you so much for your reply! This worked for me. I was not aware of ORS before, but that will be very useful for me in the future.